# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'close' was called on null. Flutter BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm trying to "close" the BLoC state. I'm basically trying to dispose the state.

Here's how my app looks like.

When I click on the "Add" TextButton, it shows an alert dialog saying that the form must be filled to proceed. When I fill the form, it generates a code and it works like a charm. Even though the debug console shows me an error that it tried calling the "close" method, but there was no such method. Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

### Code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:duckie/blocs/manual_input/manual_input_bloc.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/widgets/alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/widgets/custom_text_field.dart';
import 'package:duckie/shared/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ManualInputScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ManualInputScreenState createState() => _ManualInputScreenState();
}

class _ManualInputScreenState extends State<ManualInputScreen> {
  String secretKey;
  String issuer;
  String accountName;
  String numberOfDigits = '6';
  String timeStep = '30';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'manual-input',
          style: TextStyles.appBarText,
        ).tr(),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          BlocConsumer<ManualInputBloc, ManualInputState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is ManualInputError) {
                Platform.isAndroid
                    ? CustomAlertDialog.showAndroidAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        state.alertDialogErrorTitle,
                        state.alertDialogErrorContent)
                    : CustomAlertDialog.showIosAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        state.alertDialogErrorTitle,
                        state.alertDialogErrorContent);
              }
              ManualInputBloc manualInputBloc;
              manualInputBloc.close();
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is ManualInputInitial || state is ManualInputFinal) {
                return TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    BlocProvider.of<ManualInputBloc>(context).add(
                        GetFormTextEvent(secretKey, issuer, accountName,
                            numberOfDigits, timeStep));
                  },
                  child: Text('add').tr(),
                );
              }
              return TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('add').tr(),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'secret-key'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  secretKey = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'issuer'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                issuer = value;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'account-name'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  accountName = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Platform.isAndroid
                ? ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('number-of-digits').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      DropdownButton(
                        value: numberOfDigits,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            numberOfDigits = value;
                          });
                        },
                        items: [
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '6',
                            child: Text('6'),
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '8',
                            child: Text('8'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                : ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('number-of-digits').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                        groupValue: numberOfDigits,
                        children: {
                          '6': Text('6'),
                          '8': Text('8'),
                        },
                        onValueChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            numberOfDigits = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Platform.isAndroid
                ? ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('time-step').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      DropdownButton(
                        value: timeStep,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            timeStep = value;
                          });
                        },
                        items: [
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '30',
                            child: Text('30'),
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '60',
                            child: Text('60'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                : ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('time-step').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                        groupValue: timeStep,
                        children: {
                          '30': Text('30'),
                          '60': Text('60'),
                        },
                        onValueChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            timeStep = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### The exact code that shows an error:

```
ManualInputBloc manualInputBloc;
manualInputBloc.close();
```

### manual_input_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dart_otp/dart_otp.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'manual_input_event.dart';
part 'manual_input_state.dart';

class ManualInputBloc extends Bloc<ManualInputEvent, ManualInputState> {
  ManualInputBloc() : super(ManualInputInitial());

  @override
  Stream<ManualInputState> mapEventToState(
    ManualInputEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetFormTextEvent) {
      if (event.secretKey == null ||
          event.issuer == null ||
          event.accountName == null) {
        yield ManualInputError(
            'all-fields-error-title', 'all-fields-error-content');
      } else {
        try {
          final TOTP totp = TOTP(
            secret: event.secretKey,
            digits: int.parse(event.numberOfDigits),
            interval: int.parse(event.timeStep),
          );

          final String otp = totp.now();

          yield ManualInputFinal(
            otp,
            event.issuer,
            event.accountName,
          );
        } catch (error) {
          yield ManualInputError('totp-fail-title', 'totp-fail-content');
          print(error.toString());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you’re not initialising `manualinputBloc`. In this context the bloc would be null.

You should initialise your variable first:

```dart
ManualInputBloc manualInputBloc = ManualInputBloc();
```

edit:

in the builder method of the bloc is also not an appropriate place to initiate or close the bloc. This is how you want to change your state class:

```dart
class _yourState extends State<YourState> {
 ManualInputBloc manualInputBloc;

 @override
 void initState() {
   manualInputBloc = ManualInputBloc();
   manualInputBloc.add(YourEvent());
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   manualInputBloc.close();
   super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return BlocBuilder<ManualInputBloc, ManualInputState>(
     cubit: manualInputBloc,
     builder: (context, state) {
       return YourWidget();
     }
 }
```

Comment: That's funny, because when I init this class, the app actually stops working. When I execute the "close" method without initializing the class, it works like a charm, but there's an error in the debug console.

Comment: It’s because your initialising your variable in the wrong spot. I’ll edit my answer in a minute

Comment: I edited my answer, if there's still something wrong let me know!

Comment: Any ideas why it is like that?

Comment: Hmm well in your button you’re using blocprovider.of, so it’s two different bloc instances that’s being used right now. Maybe change the blocprovider.of to manualInputbloc

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably need to understand what BLOC is, what Events are and what States are.
You can not just close() bloc, because it does something on your screen.
States are things what application serves to the user. Your states should have names like: DisplayingForm, ValidatingForm, DisplayingError, DisplayingSuccess.
Events are things what user is clicking. Your events should have names like: AddDataEvent (you have only one so this is not crucial in your app)

Common flow is:
first state is DisplayingForm -> user clicks Add -> state changes to ValidatingForm then there is a fork -> on success DisplayingSuccess -> on error DisplayingError.

I you want to do something after success, for example close the window, then if(state is DisplayingSuccess) Navigator.pop(); or you can set some timer delay before pop();
or you can if(state is DisplayingSuccess) BlocProvider.of(context).add(ResetFormEvent), but you need to handle in your bloc an event ResetFormEvent which at the end will yield DisplayingForm state once again.
And you should communicate with bloc using .add(SomeEvent), not .close() method. Cubit is kind of bloc which enables to execute methods on it instead of events.